# Python3:How to get title eng from url?

Tags: python-3.x, url

i ues this code

```
import urllib.request
fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://english-thai-dictionary.com/dictionary/?sa=all")
mybytes = fp.read()
mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
print(mystr)
x = 'alt'
for item in mystr.split():
    if (x) in item:
        print(item.strip())
```

I get Thai word from this code but I didn't know how to get Eng word.Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want to use this url: https://english-thai-dictionary.com/dictionary/?sa=all;ftlang=then?

Comment: still can't do.

Comment: You mean you want get English words from html table from page?

Comment: Yes.I want English and Thai words on that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get words from table you should use parsing library like [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here is an example how you can parse this (I'm using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master) to fetch and [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) here to parse data):

First using dev tools in your browser identify table with content you want to parse. Table with translations has `servicesT` class attribute which occurs only once in whole document:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://english-thai-dictionary.com/dictionary/?sa=all;ftlang=then'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


# Get table with translations
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'servicesT'})
```

After that you need to get all rows that contain translations for Thai words. If you look up page's source file you will notice that first few `<tr` rows are headers that contain only headers so we will omit them. After that we wil get all `<td>` elements from row (in that table there are always 3 `<td>` elements) and fetch words from them (in this table words are actually nested in  and ).

```py
table_rows = table.findAll('tr') 
# We will skip first 3 rows beacause those are not
# contain information we need
for tr in table_rows[3:]:
    # Finding all <td> elements
    row_columns = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(row_columns) >= 2:
        # Get tag with Thai word
        thai_word_tag = row_columns[0].select_one('span > a')
        # Get tag with English word
        english_word_tag = row_columns[1].find('span')
        if thai_word_tag:
            thai_word = thai_word_tag.text
        if english_word_tag:
            english_word = english_word_tag.text
        # Printing our fetched  words
        print((thai_word, english_word))
```

Of course, this is very basic example of what I managed to parse from page and you should decide for yourself what you want to scrape. I've also noticed that data inside table does not have translations all the time so you should keep that in mind when scraping data. You also can use [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) library to parse data (it supports pagination which is present in table on page you want to scrape).